# The moderator queue is no longer a queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, moderator-abilities

The items in the moderator queue are no longer showing up in order from newest to oldest.  As I write this, the items in the list on Stack Overflow have the following time stamps:

```
2 hours ago  
3 mins ago  
1 min ago  
11 min ago  
...
```

There was a recent update (which I really like, by the way) that adds a note to each item in the list when a moderator performs some action on the flagged post.  If this is related, is the new order `[status-bydesign]`?  If not, can we get it changed back to the newest-to-oldest order?

Comment: Most likely they've realized my flags are more important than everyone else's and listed them first

Comment: @Michael: Ah, so now it's a priority queue.  I should have guessed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is some truth in Michael's answer; we're playing with things that should make the most *pressing* issues appear first, to make moderation easier. I also plan on merging the three tabs, and tracking the number of mods that have viewed a post without doing anything urgently.

All suggestions and feedback welcome here.

To be specific, in addition to taking the *cumulative* flags into account, there is a subtle variation between users; users with a history of flags *that lead to action by moderators* will be ranked a little bit above users who have a history of false-positive flags.

Comment: Feedback: Make me a mod so I can help!

Comment: Will there be a way to see your own 'flag score'. (% of flags acted on by a mod) If it is low, maybe the person could work to improve the number, and thus reducing the amount of flags mods have to deal with.

Comment: You could also associate a badge with your 'flag score' to even further motivate people to flag correctly.

Comment: I like the sound of this.  I hate to play favorites, but I'd be lying if I said I don't already have a list of names in my head (mostly positive).  When you track the number of mods who have viewed a post, can you indicate to me if *I've* already viewed it?  That would fix my issue with the newest-to-oldest ordering.

Comment: @Bill - sure; maybe even dim the ones you've actively viewed

Comment: @Bill - my immediate problem there is figuring out where best to track that ;p

Comment: @Marc One table per mod per flag, naturally. `CREATE TABLE HasBillTheLizardSeenFlag12345(boolean b); INSERT INTO HasBillTheLizardSeenFlag12345 VALUES(true);`

Comment: @Michael see, I was going for `CREATE DATABASE ...`

Comment: @Marc: The new changes that rolled out today look fantastic!  Thank you.