# Add some new sorting options to the flag queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, flags

We already have a sort order for the moderator queue that sorts flags by a certain "Order of Importance."

However, I don't work the queue from top to bottom.  Frequently, I will dispatch the "Not an answer" flags first, because they are by far the easiest to process (I can do about twelve per minute; it takes me about 5 seconds to decide on each one).  In the past, these used to cluster together, making them easy to handle at once.

Then I will do the spam flags (if I can find them).  Then I will do the off-topic ones (If I have any time left).  Because I am not constantly changing gears mentally, I believe I get more done by working this way.

Please give me a new sort option that sorts "Not an Answer" to the top. Give me one that sorts "Off Topic" to the top. Give me one that sorts spam or offensive flags to the top. That way I can prioritize my work, and I'm not constantly context-switching (i.e. I can focus on one type of flag at a time).

Note that this is probably only a problem on SO (and maybe SU) due to the sheer number of flags.

The flag weight can still be used to prioritize the flags within each sorting.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90154/show-a-different-flag-list-for-each-moderator

Comment: That explains why my flags are taking so much longer to get reviewed :)

Comment: this will be nearly impossible under the current scheme since the subtypes are only text. May take quite a while to do.

Comment: @Jeff: A sort on the subtype (with a secondary sort on flag weight) would be adequate. That way all of the flags for each subtype would cluster together.